# Add custom inspections to Resharper

Tags: c#, resharper, static-analysis

I would like to add new custom inspections to Resharper. Please consider the screenshot at the bottom. This means that I need a possibility to traverse the abstract syntax tree (or PSI in Jetbrains terms).

How can I implement that? Are there any examples?

Furthermore, how can I export my rules configuration to XML and import it on my second notebook?

Thanks for your consideration!

[resharper-inspections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4buv8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a plugin to do this. You can find out more in the [developer's guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk/README.html).

As for some samples, here's one that does [Cyclomatic Complexity checking](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-cyclomatic-complexity), and then there are a [lot of inspections in the Unity support](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/tree/master/resharper/src/resharper-unity/Daemon/Stages/Analysis)

Comment: That's a good starting point. As for my second question, is there a possibility to export my rules configuration to XML or something similar?

Comment: You can take a look at the "Import and Export" action in the "Manage Options" dialog. This will give you a tree of items to export - you'll want to look at the "Code Inspections" node. AIUI, though, it will only export values that are different to the defaults.